# Populate dataGrid with a dataTable

Tags: c#

I have the following method as you see tbl_tablas is type DataTable

```
 public DataTable tbl_tablas;
        public void crear_trigger(Form log)
        {
            tbl_tablas = Traer_informacion("SELECT TABLE_NAME,Activo FROM tblTablaLog WHERE Activo = 'True' ", set_getcadena_orginen);
            log.Show();
            try
            {
                foreach (DataRow r_tabla in tbl_tablas.Rows)
                {                
                    string creacion_tri_in = "";
                    string creacion_tri_Up = "";
                    string creacion_tri_eli = "";
                    string columnas_orig = "";
                    campos_tablas = new DataTable();
                    campos_tablas = Traer_informacion("SELECT  COL.name AS columna,TYP.name AS Tipo, Longitud = CASE TYP.name  WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN COL.LENGTH/2 WHEN 'varchar' THEN COL.LENGTH/2 ELSE COL.LENGTH END  FROM dbo.syscolumns COL JOIN dbo.sysobjects OBJ ON OBJ.id = COL.id JOIN dbo.systypes TYP ON TYP.xusertype = COL.xtype  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysforeignkeys FK ON FK.fkey = COL.colid AND FK.fkeyid=OBJ.id  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects OBJ2 ON OBJ2.id = FK.rkeyid  LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns COL2 ON COL2.colid = FK.rkey AND COL2.id = OBJ2.id   WHERE OBJ.name =  '" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "' AND (OBJ.xtype='U' OR OBJ.xtype='V') and COL.colstat!=1 group by  COL.name ,TYP.name, COL.LENGTH ", set_getcadena_orginen);
                    creacion_tri_in = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_insertarLog_" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] AFTER  insert AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid group by client_net_address)   SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;";
                    creacion_tri_Up = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_ActualizarLog_" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] AFTER  update AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid  group by client_net_address)  SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF; ";
                    creacion_tri_eli = "CREATE TRIGGER  [dbo].[Tr_EliminarLog_" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] On [" + set_getbase_orginen + "].[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] AFTER  delete AS DECLARE @ipPC VARCHAR(50) SET @ipPC = (SELECT client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid  group by client_net_address)  SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;";
                    for (int j = 0; j < campos_tablas.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == campos_tablas.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            columnas_orig += "" + campos_tablas.Rows[j]["columna"].ToString() + " ";
                        }
                        else
                               if (j < campos_tablas.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            columnas_orig += "" + campos_tablas.Rows[j]["columna"].ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    //TRIGGER INSERT
                    creacion_tri_in += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + " ,[TRANSACCION1],    [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1] ,C_ejecutada,Puesto_T) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'INSERCION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50) ,HOST_NAME()  as esta FROM INSERTED ) SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; ";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_in, set_getcadena_orginen);
                    //TRIGGER UPDATE 
                    creacion_tri_Up += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + " ,[TRANSACCION1] ,   [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1],C_ejecutada ,Puesto_T) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'ACTUALLIZACION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50 ),HOST_NAME()  as esta  FROM INSERTED )SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_Up, set_getcadena_orginen);
                    //TRIGGER DELETE
                    creacion_tri_eli += "insert into " + set_getbase_destino + ".[dbo].[" + r_tabla["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] (" + columnas_orig + ",[TRANSACCION1] ,   [FECHATRANSACCION1] ,   [USUARIOTRANSACCION1] , [ipPC1],C_ejecutada,Puesto_T ) (select top 1 " + columnas_orig + ", 'ELIMINACION' AS transaccion,getdate() as FECHATRANSACCION,SUSER_SNAME() as USUARIOTRANSACCION ,@ipPC ,(SELECT  details.text FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (requests.plan_handle) details WHERE   requests.session_id > 50  ) ,HOST_NAME()  as esta  FROM DELETED)SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; ";
                    Ejectar_consultas(creacion_tri_eli, set_getcadena_orginen);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                set_geterror = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
        }
```

When executing that tbl_tablas it is filled with the following

[image]

I have to send the data from the DataTable to a DataGrid

The DataTable is in a class and in a layer called LogicaLog and the DataGrid is in a form called TablasLog

I am sending it as follows

I open the form
[image]

I install the class where the DataTable is and assign it to the DataGrid

```
using Logica;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PuntosDeVentaLog
{
    public partial class TablasLog : Form
    {
        LogicaLog r = new LogicaLog();
        public TablasLog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();       
        }

        private void TablasLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = r.tbl_tablas;
        }

    }
}
```

But when
tbl_tablas reaches DataGird arrives Null

[image]

Comment: We prefer code to be posted as text, not images.

Comment: Posting images of code is like putting an image with a nugget on a plate

Comment: I will keep it in mind for the next :(

Comment: The post has an edit link at the bottom you can use.

Comment: What is `LogicalLog`?  The only thing you call is its constructor, what happens in that constructor?  It looks like the value you want to populate is populated in `crear_trigger`, where is that ever called?

Comment: LogicaLog It is the class where the create_trigger method is

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo: Okay, and where do you ever call that method?  (It's possible I'm missing it since I can't search for text in an *image*.  Please update the question to include *code*, not *pictures of code*.)

Comment: I already corrected it

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo: And now that one can search the code, perform a search on this page (Ctrl-F5) for the method name "crear_trigger".  There's no code here which calls that method.  You create an instance of your class: `LogicaLog r = new LogicaLog();`  And then you try to read the value on that instance: `dataGridView1.DataSource = r.tbl_tablas;`  Nowhere (in the code shown) do you ever initialize the value on that instance.

Comment: Please explain that I have to call the create_trigger method something like this,  `dataGridView1.DataSource = r.crear_trigger (); `

Comment: I would try at least calling the crear_trigger method other wise how is the LogicaLog type r going to have any data at all.

Comment: But I don't know how I have to call that method and then call the tbl_tablas

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo: The form structure looks very convoluted here.  Something calls `crear_trigger` and passes it an instance of a `Form`.  `crear_trigger` then shows that `Form`.  That `Form` internally has a reference to *another* instance of the class which has `crear_trigger`.  Why?  These things are inter-connected in strange and confusing ways.  Maybe `TablasLog` shouldn't have its own instance of `LogicaLog` but should be provided with an existing instance?  The overall structure here is difficult to follow and the intent is unclear.